# How to store console output for each while loop step in one text file using Ruby $stdout?

Tags: ruby, file-io, console, stdout

Hi I want to store whole console out put generated by all steps of while loop using.
I can store console output in one text file for first step of while loop but after this my loop is terminated.
Code snippet is below:

```
while line = f.gets do
    puts "value: #{line}"
    newuri = a.to_s.gsub('fuzz',"#{line}")
    print "Attack Request:\n\n#{newuri}\n"
    nuri = URI.parse("#{newuri}")
    Net::HTTP.start(nuri.host, nuri.port) do |http|
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new nuri.request_uri
    response = http.request request 
    puts "Response"
    puts response.body
            $stdout = File.new('out.txt','w')
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit that your question is a little unclear. I assume that you have a file with addresses, and you want to have a file with the responses received from these addresses.

Why are you trying to redefine `$stdout`? Maybe all you need is to `puts` the text *directly* to the `"out.txt"` file?

Try this: *(I have removed all "unimportant" details)*

```
File.open('out.txt','w') do |outfile|
  while line = f.gets do
    puts         "value: #{line}" # This is a "debug" info
    outfile.puts "value: #{line}" # This goes to the output file
    # ...
    Net::HTTP.start(nuri.host, nuri.port) do |http|
      request = Net::HTTP::Get.new nuri.request_uri
      response = http.request request 
      outfile.puts "Response"
      outfile.puts response.body
    end
  end
end
```

So, if I understood your problem correctly, you do usually do not need to "redefine" standard output, but you just have to put the data into the correct file. The method `puts` exists also for opened files, and just "by default" writes to the standard output.

In addition, I suggest using standard error instead standard output if you want some debugging information *(not in this snippet of code - just in some other situations where it might be useful)*:

```
$stderr.puts "Some warning"
```

or

```
STDERR.puts "Some warning"
```

..whichever looks better for you. Both variable and the constant contain the same object.